# How to simulate 1000 vehicles in veins/omnet?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I tried to simulate 1000 vehicles on the Veins erlangen example. But the   simulator always stop around 700 vehicles and displays error messages. I can simulate 500 vehicles. Why I can't simulate 1000 vehicles?

> RUNTIME ERROR. A cRuntimeError exception is about to be thrown, and
>   you requested (by setting debug-on-errors=true in the ini file) that
>   errors abort execution and break into the debugger.
>
> You should now probably be running the simulation under gdb or another
>   debugger. The simulation kernel will now raise a SIGABRT signal which
>   will get you into the debugger. If you are not running under a
>   debugger, you can still use the core dump for post-mortem debugging.
>   Once in the debugger, view the call stack (in gdb: "bt" command) to
>   see the context of the runtime error.
>
> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd)
>   RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6) at event #21128, t=2112.7:
>   std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc.

[image]

```
<pre>
[General]
cmdenv-express-mode = true
cmdenv-autoflush = true
cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s

#tkenv-default-config = debug
#tkenv-default-run = 1
ned-path = .

network = RSUExampleScenario

##########################################################
#            Simulation parameters                       #
##########################################################
debug-on-errors = true
print-undisposed = false

#sim-time-limit = 6000s
sim-time-limit = 8000s

**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true

**.debug = false
**.coreDebug = false

*.playgroundSizeX = 2500m
*.playgroundSizeY = 2500m
*.playgroundSizeZ = 50m
#*.playgroundSizeX = 7500m #ME ADDED
#*.playgroundSizeY = 7500m #ME ADDED
#*.playgroundSizeZ = 500m #ME ADDED


##########################################################
# Annotation parameters                                  #
##########################################################
*.annotations.draw = false

##########################################################
# Obstacle parameters                                    #
##########################################################
*.obstacles.debug = false
*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("config.xml",   "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")

##########################################################
#            WorldUtility parameters                     #
##########################################################
*.world.useTorus = false
*.world.use2D = false

##########################################################
#            TraCIScenarioManager parameters             #
##########################################################
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car"
*.manager.moduleName = "node"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.margin = 25
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("erlangen.launchd.xml")

##########################################################
#                       RSU SETTINGS                     #
#                                                        #
#                                                        #
##########################################################
*.rsu[0].mobility.x = 2000
*.rsu[0].mobility.y = 2000
*.rsu[0].mobility.z = 3
*.rsu[*].applType = "TraCIDemoRSU11p"
*.rsu[*].appl.debug = false
*.rsu[*].appl.headerLength = 256 bit
*.rsu[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
*.rsu[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.rsu[*].appl.sendData = true
*.rsu[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
*.rsu[*].appl.beaconPriority = 3
*.rsu[*].appl.dataPriority = 2
*.rsu[*].appl.maxOffset = 0.005s


##########################################################
#            11p specific parameters                     #
#                                                        
# NIC-Settings                        #
##########################################################
*.connectionManager.pMax = 20mW
*.connectionManager.sat = -89dBm
*.connectionManager.alpha = 2.0
*.connectionManager.carrierFrequency = 5.890e9 Hz
*.connectionManager.sendDirect = true

*.**.nic.mac1609_4.useServiceChannel = false

*.**.nic.mac1609_4.txPower = 20mW
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 18Mbps

*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
*.**.nic.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true
*.**.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm
*.**.nic.phy80211p.decider = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.analogueModels = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.usePropagationDelay = true

##########################################################
#                    WaveAppLayer                        #
##########################################################
*.node[*].applType = "TraCIDemo11p"
*.node[*].appl.debug = false
*.node[*].appl.headerLength = 256 bit
*.node[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
*.node[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.node[*].appl.sendData = true
*.node[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
*.node[*].appl.beaconPriority = 3
*.node[*].appl.dataPriority = 2
*.node[*].appl.maxOffset = 0.005s

##########################################################
#                      Mobility                          #
##########################################################
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType =      "org.car2x.veins.modules.mobility.traci.TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType = "TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobility.x = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.y = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.z = 1.895
#*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 0
#*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 75s
#*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 30s
*.node[5].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 0
*.node[5].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 15s
*.node[5].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 35s
*.node[10].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 0
*.node[10].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 35s
*.node[10].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 35s

[Config nodebug]
description = "default settings"
**.debug = false
**.coreDebug = false
*.annotations.draw = false

[Config debug]
description = "(very slow!) draw and print additional debug information"
**.debug = true
**.coreDebug = true
*.annotations.draw = true

</pre>
```

Comment: Fortunately the SO is full with telepaths and they can read out your mind, what is your code, what are these error messages and thus they can answer it without requiring from you to write 5 lines more.

Comment: Btw, I tried to save your question by fixing its spelling, but next time you won't be so lucky and your question will be simply closed. If you aren't sure what are the most common and most annoying spelling mistakes, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is a trivial checklist for you. And paste your code here, paste the error messages too, and do it fast, or your question will be closed!

Comment: Alright, I will upload the error messages asap. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you ran out of memory. From a back-of-the-envelope calculation, Veins needs approx 400 KByte of memory to simulate each vehicle. This means, you need 400 MByte of memory to simulate 1000 vehicles - significantly more if you run the graphical user interface.

From that, I can derive two possible answers to your question: first, run your simulation in command line mode (see the user's manual for how to do that). Second, make sure you have at least 0.4 GByte of main memory free.

Comment: Dr Chris,                                                                                                  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used to increase end time in commands once i generate the map to simulate more vehicles and it works
f.g. python c:\sumo\sumo25\tools\randomTrips.py -n map.net.xml -e 200 -l